# MSI installer with c# WPF VS 2015

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windows-installer

I have created a simple wpf application in c# with only one window, MainWindow.xaml. There is no database, not even textboxes, not a single line of code added by myself.

[file structure wpf project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIzDj.png)

I also created an MSI setup project:

[setup project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmV9p.png)

Building of either project works without problem. However, after installation, when I try to run the programme crashes without any error message. All that I see is that the circle-turned cursor is spinning and the windows explorer window can no longer be closed.

Operating system is Windows 10. Anyone has had a similar experience? Looks like a bug in the MSI installer.

Comment: Take a look at the Event Logs, there might be an entry for the crash with further information

Comment: @cFrozenDeath: No entries in the Event Log.

Answer (score 0):

Check all the .dll's are included in the installer.  Often not all of them are and you need to manually include them.  You can compare what's in the install (C:\Program Files...) directory compared to what's in the project bin directory.  Often times items like "PresentationFramework.Aero.dll" aren't included and you get a missing .dll error.

If this is the case, you can copy over some of the .dll's until it works.  Then add those to the installer.

Comment: You can try running the installation on your dev machine - right click on the installer project - if this works whereas it fails when installed on another box, it suggests missing dll's

Comment: @peterG: It does not even work in the dev machine. I have given up and went for InstallShield instead. The latter seems to be working fine. Thank you for your input.

Comment: You can debug your application and find out, what's going on. You can find an error in event viewer too.